# Set up Twitter account from Settings iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, settings

I'm currently working on xcode 5. In my app the Launch Image is coming from Twitter, & for that I need to setup my twitter account first, from default settings in iPhone.

Therefore, when I open my app it will display the image downloaded from Twitter, only if I have set up my account in settings.

Now my problem is what if I have not set up my Twitter account from settings & trying to open app? Currently it is coming as blank as expected. But what could be the solution for this?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Twitter.framework you could always check whether a twitter account is synced from the device or not by this property

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) ACAccount *account;
```

in TWRequest.h

If you are using Social.framework also there is a similar property

```
@property (retain, NS_NONATOMIC_IOSONLY) ACAccount *account;
```

In SLRequest.h

The above property returns Nil, I tried these statements in simulator and it worked

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init] ;
ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
NSArray *twitterAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType];

if(twitterAccounts)
{
    NSLog(@"twitterAccounts: %@",twitterAccounts);
}
```

I got my twitter account details synced in the simulator in the array, hope it works the same in device too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Give +1 as I promised to appreciate any help. Now let me know how to use account? As I'm totally novice to ACAccount

Answer (score 1):

Well a simple solution is create a placeholder image (or text) instead of the image where you say: "If you want to enable all the functionalities go to settings and set up user account". Of course as early as possible you should check the existance of at least one twitter account.

Comment: Hey Andrea thank you for your answer. Take +1 as I promised to appreciate any help. But unfortunetly this is not my ansewr. Yes, I definitely will use the placeholder. But my question is how to check the twiiter account set up from the app

Comment: Sorry..thanks anyway. The answer from satheeshwaran is correct, if twitterAccounts.count == 0 menas that you should set one in settings.